# Location of EPS file while inserting into LaTeX file

Tags: graphics, external-files

Where should my files be located for inserting them into LaTeX document. Please help me.

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.87]{Plot_Left_Right.eps}  
  \caption{Banknote Left vs Right}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: When using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), you don't need to specify the file extension. A list of default extensions are added depending on the driver used. See [Graphics extensions and their order of inclusion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72930/5764).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your given snippet the image has to be in the same directory of your `tex` file.

In my opinion it is better to use a directory `images` for example.  Then you have to include the relative path `images/` in the call of `\includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[scale=.87]{images/Plot_Left_Right.eps}
```