# Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified

Tags: graphics, external-files

When using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\includegraphics` you can specify the file extension or not. For generic use and perhaps portability, extensions are commonly dropped. The types of "approved" inclusions and their order of precedence depends on the driver/compiler being used. What are these driver-defaults?

Related: [Which graphics formats can be included in documents processed by `latex` or `pdflatex`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1072/5764)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### `pdftex.def`

Version 2011/05/28 v0.06e

The list depends on

- the version of `pdftex.def`,
- the version of pdfTeX (temporarily TIFF was available, latest addition is JBIG2),
- the version of the generated PDF (JBIG2 requires PDF 1.4).

For the current versions (2012) and PDF ≥ 1.4, the list is:

```
.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2
```

The order of the list is not optimal, it is a victim of compatibility.

The list can be extended by package `epstopdf` that adds `.eps` to the list and provide means to support further image formats.

### `dvips.def`

Version: 1999/02/16 v3.01i

```
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z
```

Other supported extensions:

```
.pcx,.bmp,.msp,.pict,.pntg
```

### `dvipdfm.def`

Version: 1999/9/6 vx.x (Bug: should be 1999/09/06)

```
.jpg,.jpeg,.pdf,.png
```

Also supported are EPS files.

### `dvipdfmx.def`

Version: 1999/02/16 v3.0i

```
.pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.bmp,.ps,.eps,.pz,.eps.Z,.ps.Z,.ps.gz,.eps.gz
```

### `xetex.def`

Version: 2009/11/22 v0.94

```
.pdf,.eps,.ps,.png,.jpg,.bmp,.pict,.tif,.psd,.mac,.sga,.tga,.gif
```

### `vtex.def`

Version 2001/10/02 v7.45

```
.gif,.png,.jpg,.tif,.bmp,.tga,.pcx,.eps,.ps,.mps,.emf,.wmf
(also .tiff, .targa, .jpeg)
```

### Other drivers in the graphics bundle

Version: 1999/02/16 v3.0i

```
dvipdf.def:  .eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z
dvipson.def: .eps,.ps,.pcx,.bmp (also .tif)
dviwin.def:  .eps,.ps,.wmf,.tif
emtex.def:   .eps,.ps,.pcx,.bmp
pctex32.def: .eps,.ps,.wmf,.bmp
pctexhp.def: .pcl
pctexps.def: .eps.ps
pctexwin.def: .eps,.ps,.wmf,.bmp
tcidvi.def:   <empty> (also .ps,.eps,.PS,.EPS and BMP)
truetex.def:  .eps,.ps (also .tif,.bmp)
```

### List manipulation

I recommend package [`grfext`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/grfext.pdf) for manipulating the list of graphics extensions.

- Extensions can be added: `\AppendGraphicsExtensions`, `\PrependGraphicsExtensions`.
- Extensions can be removed: `\RemoveGraphicsExtensions`.

For example, prefer vector graphics over bitmap graphics, indenpendent of the driver:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grfext}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \PrependGraphicsExtensions*{
    .mps,.MPS,.pdf,.PDF,.eps,.EPS,.ps,.PS,
    .png,.PNG,.jpg,.jpeg,.JPG,.JPEG,
    .funny,.foobar
  }%
  \PrintGraphicsExtensions % see .log file
}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Package `grfext` prints the list in the `.log` file (example for pdflatex/TL2011):

```
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.mps,.pdf,.PDF,.eps,.png,.PNG,.jpg,.jpeg,.JPG,.JPEG,.jbig2,.jb2,.JBIG2,.JB2]
```

The star form of `\PrependGraphicsExtensions` only adds the extensions that are supported by the graphics driver.

Answer (score 20):

The defaults are defined in the driver files, not by `graphicx` itself. A simple way to see them is to use `texdef`, e.g. `texdef -t pdflatex -p graphicx Gin@extensions`.

For `latex` in DVI mode the default extension list is `.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z`, for `pdflatex` and `lualatex` it is `.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps` and for `xelatex` it is `.pdf,.eps,.ps,.png,.jpg,.bmp,.pict,.tif,.psd,.mac,.sga,.tga,.gif`.

Comment: I have always wondered why `.png` has precedence over `.pdf` in `pdflatex`. I mean, if you have a vector and a bitmap version of the same image, the bitmap version should be preferred? Does anybody have a clue about the rationale behind this?

Comment: @Daniel Compatibility.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Yes, but ... compatibility to what? Given that PNG is (historically) newer than PDF and no other driver seems to give PNG precedence over PDF this seems to be quite strange.

Comment: @Daniel Compatibility to older versions of `pdftex.def`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Sorry to bug you, but ... this brings us just back to the original question of rationale: I perfectly understand the compatibility argument, but still do not understand why PNG ever had precedence over PDF in `pdftex.def` (i.e., in its very first version)?

Comment: @Daniel I am the wrong person to ask, because my maintenance does not start from the very beginning. PDF is much more complicate for including. Perhaps PNG was earlier supported by pdfTeX or PDF inclusion was too unstable in early versions of pdfTeX.

Answer (score 2):

If someone came here because he/she tried to take e.g. `.png`s instead of `.pdf`s for the draft, put this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf}
```

Feel free to adapt this to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

As of ~2021 (MiKTeX 21.7), it seems the order has been updated.  (install directory e.g. MiKTeX)\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def, line 586:

```
\def\Gin@extensions{%
  .pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,%
  .PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2%
}
```