# Can I use webp images in Latex?

Tags: graphics

I have an .webp image that I want to use in my Latex document. However, I can't really find how to use it or is it simply not possible with Latex?

Comment: Under pdfTeX (perhaps the most versatile), you can only include a fixed number of image types. See [Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72930/5764). I would assume that you should convert the image to one of these.

Comment: Ok, also see the comment @DavidCarlisle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably need to convert the image to png. A freely available convertor precompiled for windows/linux/mac is available from

https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download

then

```
dwebp image.webp -o image.png
```

should produce a usable file.

Comment: The link suggests it's a conversion tool *to* `.webp`. Does it also convert *from* `.webp`?

Comment: Well, I was hoping Latex would support it or that there would be a package available to add this function.

Comment: well if you want latex to do it on the fly you could enable shell escape and set up a graphics rule for `.webp` such that it executes the conversion (a lot of people do this for eps/pdf conversion in pdftex) but really it's simpler just to convert it once and include the png directly unless it is changing all the time.

Comment: Mac users: `brew install webp`.

Comment: Ubuntu (Linux) users: `sudo apt install webp`

Comment: I noticed that wbp images are much smaller than the converted PNG or PDF. Random example: from 67kb to 814kb. More and more images are available in the wbp format.

Comment: @PatrickT but unless the pdf format is changed to support webp, including them in latex will necesarily  be slower and not have smaller final pdf  as each webp will need to be converted to a form that can be included

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, makes sense, thanks for the clarification David!