# Compiling a Latex template to a PDF file

Tags: texniccenter

I'm trying to compile a LaTeX template to a PDF, but it's not working. The template is available in this [link](http://www.versita.com/nanommta/authors/) (on the right side in Article Templates).

I'm using TeXnic Center. Can anyone please try to compile this and let me know if it's working.

Comment: What error are you getting, precisely? You can find the error in the file yourfilename.log. You should also try to reduce your problem to a minimal (non) working example (MWE), and then post it here as a code snippet, to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: It compiles fine to PDF for me if I delete the `DVI` from the `\documentclass` line.

Comment: It would be better if you could strip the file down to a MWE that doesn't compile for you. Directing users off the site to a `zip` file might not be well received by everyone :)

Comment: Which Output Profile did you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No answer for almost two weeks, so here my guess: *You’ve chosen the wrong output profile for compiling.*

The template file `NanoMMTA_template.tex`, available in the ZIP file to be found from your link, clearly states in the preamble:

```
%% put the discipline from the list below"
%% chemistry, biology, physics, mathematics, medicine
\documentclass[mathematics,DVI]{ejs_author}
% if you use PostScript figures in your article
% use the graphics package for simple commands
\usepackage{graphics}
% or use the graphicx package for more complicated commands
\usepackage{graphicx}
% or use the epsfig package if you prefer to use the old commands
\usepackage{epsfig}
```

Note the `DVI` as documentclass option. So you need an output profile in TeXnicCenter, what creates a DVI file in first step. Supposed you have the default profile configuration these are the following:

- LaTeX ⇨ DVI
- LaTeX ⇨ DVI ⇨ PDF
- LaTeX ⇨ PS (what actually is LaTeX ⇨ DVI ⇨ PS)
- LaTeX ⇨ PS ⇨ PDF (again: actually LaTeX ⇨ DVI ⇨ PS ⇨ PDF)

After choosing the graphics package *(I would opt for `graphicx`)* the compilation went fine here.

In fact the cause of the problem is the inclusion of an EPS file:

```
\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=6cm]{nano-mmta-fig.eps}% Here is how to import EPS art
```

This file type is not supported in `pdftex` mode (“LaTeX ⇨ PDF”), cf. [Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72930/graphics-file-extensions-and-their-order-of-inclusion-when-not-specified).

***Remark:***

Looking into the class file `ejs_author.cls` you can see, that beside the option `DVI` there is also a `PDF` one, and this is even the default option. Usually for on-the-fly conversion from EPs to a `pdftex` supported format the package and script `epstopdf` is recommended. In TeX Live this happens automatic while compilation, in MiKTeX you need to add `\usepackage{epstopdf}` *after* `usepackage{graphicx}`.

But in this case here the EPS file is a bit special (a bitmap file just embedded in a bounding box), and in the result the included image is defunct both in MiKTeX and TeX Live. In MiKTeX there is no cure in such a case *(but use one of the DVI modes)*, in TeX Live I had success in using the Perl script `epstopdf.pl` with some Ghostscript options:

```
perl C:\texlive\texmf-dist\scripts\epstopdf\epstopdf.pl --gs --gscmd=C:\Programs\Ghostscript\bin\gswin32c.exe --outfile=e2p-nanofig.pdf nano-mmta-fig.eps
```

<sup>(Paths must be adjusted. Help with adding the option `--help`.)</sup>

I’ve got a warning `==> Warning: BoundingBox not found`, what perhaps is the actual reason for all the mess, but the resulting PDF file shows the image, so I could use it replacing the original `\includegraphics` command:

```
\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=6cm]{e2p-nanofig.pdf}
```

The image is a bit cutted on the right and distorted. Only the distortion can be cured by setting a bounding box in `\includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[width=12cm,height=6cm,bb=20mm 10mm 218mm 165mm]{e2p-nanofig.pdf}
```