# Including Bitmap (.bmp)

Tags: graphics, floats

I can't include bitmaps with pdflatex. Here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\addto\extrasturkish{\uccode`i=\string"9D \lccode`I=\string"19 }
\addto\noextrasturkish{\uccode`i=`I \lccode`I=`i }


\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\shorthandoff{=}
 \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm]{000.bmp}
\end{document}
```

Gives the error `Unknown graphics extension: .bmp.`

Comment: `pdftex` can include only PNG, JPEG, JBIG2 and PDF graphic files. Convert the BMP to PNG.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As egreg has pointed out, It is preferable to have `.pdf`, `.png` or even `.eps` (with under the shell conversion to pdf) figure formats for `pdflatex` . `Convert` is command line script from [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). You can [install it](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) on any platform. Type in the command line prompt `convert 000.bmp 000.png` .

A decent documentation of [graphics in LaTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf) is always handy.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Heiko Oberdiek’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72939) to [Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72930/graphics-file-extensions-and-their-order-of-inclusion-when-not-specified) another solution without image conversion consists in either producing a DVI file, then (a) converting this with `dvips` to PS, what then with `ps2pdf` can further converted to PDF or (b) directly converting the DVI to PDF with `dvipdfmx` *(note the `x`, it’s important here)* – (a)/(b) are in most TeX editors reachable with one mouse click/key stroke –, or using Xe(La)TeX.

<sup>If you take a deeper look on Heiko’s answer: There are obviously even some other possibilities with more rarely used TeX drivers.</sup>