# Use .ico images in latex

Tags: graphics, article

I have a lot of icon (.ico) files which I would prefer to use in a document. Is it possible to include such a file (through packages or some such) in a LaTeX document?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}%                          Using images

%Define inline icons, 20% lower than baseline
\newcommand{\icon}[1]{\raisebox{-.1\height}{\includegraphics[height=3ex]{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    Tap \icon{Logo}\ icon
\end{document}
```

I understand that I can convert them to `.png`, `.jpg`, `.pdf` etc and will do so eventually.

**Distro**: Texlive

**OS**: Fedora 20 (Virtual Box)

**IDE**: TeXStudio

**Compiler**: Xelatex

Comment: Just convert them now, I don't think that type of images are supported in LaTeX and friends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ICO forma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format))t is an extension of the BMP graphics format in Windows. For the latter, it was already asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87276/including-bitmap-bmp) if they can be included in LaTeX documents. Since the answer back then was negative (without conversion), the same applies here as well.

Note that ICO files can include multiple versions of an icon, so take care to convert the right one. XeLaTeX can deal with PNG files, which have all of the features of BMP files, so they should be used as conversion target.

Comment: Well, since its a no-go, I will select this as the accepted answer.