# Can I use bitmap .bmp images in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, errors, dvi, bitmap

I'm on overleaf and already tried all LaTeX engines, resulting in the same error:

> LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .bmp

Is there a way to fix this rather than converting the images one by one?
I've searched about it and people were talking about DVI, but I didn't understand how it works

Comment: Read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87276/including-bitmap-bmp  In summary you should convert to *.png. Check out ImageMagick. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php

Comment: latex+dvips can include bmp but really it's an obsolete format and if using pdflatex you are best to convert them all to png you should be able to convert them all at once with a tool such as imagemagic convert

Comment: Probably all graphics editors that let you open BMP also let you export as PNG.

Comment: I've installed ImageMagick, but don't know how it works.. How do I do to convert all images of a folder?

Comment: If on Windows or WINE Irfanview can batch convert about 1000 images in  a second if you want something less geeky than imagemagick. http://www.irfanview.com/