# Append .eps to included figures

Tags: eps

Is there a way to define a new command so that existing

```
\includegraphics[scale=x]{fig_name}
```

becomes

```
\includegraphics[scale=x]{fig_name.eps}
```

for any x and fig_name? This is for automatic conversion of eps to pdf because eps may cause out of memeory issues with xdvipdfmx: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169029/xdvipdfmx-out-of-memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *all* your usages exclude the use of a file extension, then you can simply do

```
\usepackage{graphicx,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldincludegraphics}{\includegraphics}
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\oldincludegraphics[#1]{#2.eps}}
```

which would transform

```
\includegraphics[*]{**}
```

to

```
\includegraphics[*]{**.eps}
```

The use of [`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) is required in order to cope with the optional argument of `\includegraphics`. See [When to use `\LetLtxMacro`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88001/5764)

Alternatively, and perhaps much easier, you can use

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
```

See [File format preference with `graphicx`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88860/5764).