# Latex or PdfLatex to generate DVI

Tags: graphics, pdftex, compiling, dvi

I would like to generate DVI output using `latex` or `pdflatex`, it doesn't matter. First, I would like to mention that I run the following command to compile my document and it runs successfully -

`pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 report.tex`

Now if I wanted to have a DVI on the same file, I run the following command -

`latex report.tex`

I get the following error -

`! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in platform.pdf (no BoundingBox
).`

Just to mention that the figure `platform.pdf` is in pdf format which is generated using other image editing software (Microsoft Visio).

I also tried to add `%&latex` on the first line.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: DVI can neither handle the PDF format, nor many graphics format allowed by pdflatex

Comment: actually, I need to submit the DVI to the conference instead of PDF. I am wondering how should I generate DVI.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: That link explains why Raj faced that problem, but since the error message suggests there's a particular problem with this PDF message, rather than the program not handling PDF at all, the equivalence of the two problems isn't clear.  I'd rather have this not be a duplicate.

Comment: if you have a conference that specifies DVI, it might be a good idea to get one of the "great and good" to point out to them that it's not a good idea.  this issue with image formats is only one of the many that can arise for a scholar trying to prepare a paper for such a conference.

Comment: Well, its exactly the PDF eXpress tool of IEEE which needs this. The latex source must have DVI included is their requirement. You can have a look here `http://www.pdf-express.org/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>`latex.exe` cannot compile a TeX input file that imports either PDF, PNG, or JPG images. Instead, `latex.exe` can only compile a TeX input file that imports EPS images.</s>

See the [Ulrike Fischer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98713/19356) or [Martin Schroder's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98704/latex-or-pdflatex-to-generate-dvi/98706#comment213483_98706) for the correct statement.

To convert PDF to EPS, you can use `pdftops` as follows:

```
 pdftops -f 1 -l 1 -eps "input.pdf"  "output.eps"
```

Comment: I tried this `convert` utility already. It is losing the image quality to a great extent. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Rather than `convert`, I'd suggest `pdf2ps` that uses Ghostscript. But probably PDF was not the best format to begin with, if the contents is an image.

Comment: I used inkscape and got great results. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Raj: See my update. You will get a high quality EPS.

Comment: @egreg: I think `pdf2ps` does not exist.

Comment: @GarbageCollector It's part of the Ghostscript distribution, I believe.

Comment: Sorry, but that's wrong. `latex` will produce a DVI file, which can be converted to PDF with `dvipdfm` - which _does_ handle PDF, PNG, JPEG and EPS images.

Answer (score 10):

Actually LaTeX itself can handle *every* image format if you tell it the size of the graphics:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document} 
\fbox{\includegraphics[bb=0 0 200 200]{unknown.imgformat}}

\end{document}
```

The `dvi` doesn't contain the actual image but only a reference, a "link". So it doesn't matter that it doesn't exist. The problems start when you try to view, print or convert to pdf: Then the dvi driver needs to find the image and also must be able to handle it.

**Btw: This also means that it is not enough to send a `dvi` to someone else. You should also sent every image.**

The most used dvi driver, `dvips` can handle `eps` and in some variants `jpg`. With `dvipdfmx` it is also possible to use e.g. `pdf`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}

\begin{document} 
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5,bb=0 0 600 850]{tiger.pdf}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also Heiko’s answer: [Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72939).

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics), you have to convert the PDF to PS or EPS format.

You may use [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) to make the conversion.

Comment: PDF to EPS degrades image quality a lot. Do you know any good method for conversion, to not to loose the image quality?

Comment: You may play with the resolution; PDF to EPS seems to loose the vector format as you convert the PDF to a raster format. Try using a "big" resolution (like 300, 600 or 1200 dpi).

Comment: I used inkscape and got great results. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Converting your PDF to PostScript is only needed if you use `dvips` or another device driver that does not handle PDFs. But there's still `dvipdfm`, which _can_ handle PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has the same problem again in the future.

For me it worked when I used `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` instead of `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`

I was using TeXShop 3.51 on a Mac. What I also did was in TeXShop -> Preferences to go to Tab 'Typesetting' and Where it says 'Default Script' to select the radio button 'TeX+DVI' and then in the tab 'Engine' to click the checkbox 'Save Postcript File' under the 'TeX+dvips+distiller' menu.

Accepted from the IEEE PDF eXpress.

Comment: Actually, neither the `dvips` option nor `pdftex` should ever be explicitly set.