# problem with making simple lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, dvi-mode

I tried to make two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,1) -- (2,1);
\draw (1,1) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To my surprice, only lines are drawn that are at an angle of about 45 degrees.
I tried many other things, but I cannot find the clue to solve this.
Can somebody help me ? (the first time using TikZ).

Extra info: Now I found out that the problem only occurs if the output profile is LATEX --> DVI. If the output Profile is LATEX --> PDF, then there is no problem (the pdf-output are the two orthogonal lines as expected). Thus the question now becomes: Why are the lines I see in the DVI-output not the same as in the PDF-output?

Comment: You tried to make two lines and you were successful with it. Actually, the angle of these lines is 90 degrees. What is your problem to solve?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! This is what I get from your MWE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7L66.png Can you share your output?

Comment: Extra info: Now I found out that the problem ony occurs if the output profile is LATEX --> DVI. If the output Profile is LATEX --> PDF, then there is no problem (the pdf-output are the two orthogonal lines). Thus the question now becomes: Why are the lines I ssee in the DVI-output not the same as in the PDF-output?

Comment: Extra info: Now I found out that the problem ony occurs if the output profile is LATEX --> DVI. If the output Profile is LATEX --> PDF, then there is no problem (the pdf-output are the two orthogonal lines). Thus the question now becomes: Why are the lines I ssee in the DVI-output not the same as in the PDF-output?

Comment: what do you use to view the dvi file, and please show an image of your output (as a new user you may have to remove the `!` from the image link after uploading it, so it appears as a link not inline)

Comment: The dvi export of TikZ is buggy. However, why do you need the dvi output?

Answer (score 3):

I have inserted a grid. Maybe it could help you solve your problem? Let me know if I have helped you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-5:5, scale=0.65, baseline=0, >=stealth]
\draw (0,0)--(5,0);
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
\draw (\x,0)--(\x,-.1) node[anchor=north] {\x};
\draw (0,0)--(0,5);
\foreach \y in {0,...,5}
\draw (0,\y)--(-.1,\y) node[anchor=east] {\y};
\draw[step=1cm, draw=lightgray, thin] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\draw (1,1) -- (2,1);
\draw (1,1) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Extra info: Now I found out that the problem ony occurs if the output profile is LATEX --> DVI. If the output Profile is LATEX --> PDF, then there is no problem (the pdf-output are the two orthogonal lines). Thus the question now becomes: Why are the lines I ssee in the DVI-output not the same as in the PDF-output?

Comment: Extra info: Now I found out that the problem ony occurs if the output profile is LATEX --> DVI. If the output Profile is LATEX --> PDF, then there is no problem (the pdf-output are the two orthogonal lines). Thus the question now becomes: Why are the lines I ssee in the DVI-output not the same as in the PDF-output?

Comment: The file DVI is a file called Device Indipendent. Look this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98704/latex-or-pdflatex-to-generate-dvi

Comment: @JacquesSmeets by default, if using latex, tikz and the latex graphics package will use `\special` designed for the `dvips` dvi to postscript driver. If you view the dvi in an on-screen dvi viewer then you may see nothing at all or may see something if the viewer can emulate some dvips specials. Most dvi viewers though can not use full PostScript capabilities. So what you see depends on which viewer you use, If I use xdvi, the lines appear at right angles as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody cannot reproduce your issue. I think it is related to applying different scaling factors on horizontal and vertical directions.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thin,green] (0,-1) grid (3,3);
\draw (1,1) -- (2,2);
\draw (1,1) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.25]
\draw[ultra thin,green] (0,-1) grid (3,3);
\draw (1,1) -- (2,2);
\draw (1,1) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For my opinion is correct too your answer. +1 colleague.
.

Comment: Extra info: Now I found out that the problem ony occurs if the output profile is LATEX --> DVI. If the output Profile is LATEX --> PDF, then there is no problem (the pdf-output are the two orthogonal lines). Thus the question now becomes: Why are the lines I ssee in the DVI-output not the same as in the PDF-output?

Comment: Extra info: Now I found out that the problem ony occurs if the output profile is LATEX --> DVI. If the output Profile is LATEX --> PDF, then there is no problem (the pdf-output are the two orthogonal lines). Thus the question now becomes: Why are the lines I ssee in the DVI-output not the same as in the PDF-output?

Comment: I left a comment to the same query inder the other answer