# How to use "latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf" to get pdf output?

Tags: eps, dvips, ps2pdf

I am using **pdflatex** to produce a `.pdf` file. But, it is not working when `.eps` files are compiled. I have tried it with **XeLatex** but, it is hanging out sometimes. Now I want to produce a `.pdf` file using two steps : `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf`. I don't know how to use it. The location of my `.tex` file (i.e., `Myfile.tex`) is on the desktop and  the system is **Ubuntu11.04**.
As for example :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,epstopdf}  

\begin{document}
Here some text  
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=3cm,angle=0]{fig1}
\caption{First figure}
\end{center}
\end{figure}  
Here some text
\end{document}
```

How can I do so?

Comment: 1. No need for figure extension explicitly, `\includegraphics{fig1}` is good enough.  add `\usepackage{epstopdf}` after `\usepackage{graphicx}` in preamble to make `.eps` figures work with `pdflatex` for  TeXLive(2009). 2. In TeXLive 2012 it's done automatically (behind using epstopdf)without adding any package. `xelatex` handles `.eps` natively. 3. Have a look at  
Heiko Oberdiek's Answer to [Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72939/15717)

Comment: ... 4. Imp: How was the `.eps` generated ? Unless someone uses PSTricks, `pdflatex` should work fine. 5. Note place your `fig1.eps` and `.tex` in same place/folder. 6. Which editor are you using run `latex filename` then `dvips filename` and  `ps2pdf filename` there may be flags/options incase one wants to add inside editor configuration.

Comment: I am using 'kile'.I have used '\usepackage{epstopdf}'. But, it shows an error :'fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found \includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=3cm,angle=0]{fig1.eps}'

Comment: Remove file extension and enable shell escape `pdflatex -shell-escape filename`. Please post all relevant/important information like this error inside the Q and `fig.eps` file (dropbox) instead of comments so that it will be noticed by all and Q & A remains tidy and standalone.

Comment: I have updated my post removing file extension. But the same error occured. How can I enable **shell escape** ?

Comment: @texenthusiast,thank you. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Open the `terminal` application then type:

```
cd Desktop
latex yourfile.tex
dvips yourfile.dvi
ps2pdf yourfile.ps
```

(finish each line with pressing `enter`).

Answer (score 0):

I use use in such cases the following procedure:

- convert the EPS files to pdf (with `ps2pdf fig1.eps fig1.pdf`)
- use `includegraphics` or `includepdf` (from `pdfpages`) to include the formerly eps files
- use `pdflatex` as well

Use these MWE instead of yours:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}  

\begin{document}
Here some text  
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm,width=3cm,angle=0]{fig1.pdf}
\caption{First figure}
\end{center}
\end{figure}  
Here some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this process the picture quality is not better than the eps figure gives. I want to keep .eps figure in the tex file and then I want to follow my desired steps.