# Text box to insert a graphic

Tags: graphics, formatting

How can I use a text box to insert a graphic? I got the following code and I must modify it in order to insert a graphic. What should I do?

```
\begin{figure}[thpb]
      \centering
      \framebox{\parbox{3in}{We suggest that you use a text box to insert a graphic (which is ideally a 300 dpi TIFF or EPS file, with all fonts embedded) .
}}
      %\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{figurefile}
      \caption{Inductance of oscillation winding on amorphous
       magnetic core versus DC bias magnetic field}
      \label{figurelabel}
   \end{figure}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Insert a figure using the above code?

Comment: yap i have image a.tif i want to insert the figure using above code. Thanks

Comment: Well just remove the `%` symbol and replace where it says `figurefile` with the name of your figure. Ensure that you have declared the extension using the `graphicx` package. Also remember that the figure must be found in the same folder as the tex file. So it compiles smoothly

Comment: See [Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72930/5764) for a list and the order of inclusion of files when their extensions are not included. TIF files require Xe(La)TeX.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem simply stems from a line that shouldn't be commented.