# \pdfpages, box, headers

Tags: header-footer, pdfpages

I'm using `pdfpages` to put a PDF file into my latex document. The command

```
\includepdf[page=1,angle=90,height=\textheight]{file.pdf}
```

works fine but I would rather it kept the header and footer that are on every other page in the document and then had the PDF file fill in the remainder of the page. As is it kills the header and footer.

Maybe I should construct a box?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't need `\includepdf`; `\includegraphics` is sufficient and it wouldn't override the page style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following example centers an image in the text area of a new page. The image is maximized without distortion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\IncludePageImage}[2][]{%
  \newpage
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}%
    \nointerlineskip
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \includegraphics[%
      width=\textwidth,
      height=\textheight,
      keepaspectratio,
      #1%
    ]{#2}%
    \par
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    \newpage
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \IncludePageImage{file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The page layout can be made visible by option `showframe` of package `geometry`:

```
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
```

Option `pass` is useful, if the layout is defined without package `geometry`. Then package `geometry` lets the layout parameter untouched if option `pass` is given.

Comment: @Speravir: Extension changed to `.pdf`. But other supported image extensions also work.

Comment: Yes, thankfully you already have listed this: [Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72939).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody. I ended up using

```
\includepdf[page=1,angle=90,height=\textheight,pagecommand={\pagestyle{fancy}}]{file.pdf}
```

but all the other info is great for the future.

Comment: Hi Andrew. A tip: note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.