# includegraphics without file extension

Tags: graphics

How can I use includegraphics when I want to include an image which has no extension?

When I try to set `type=jpg` by hand I get the following error:
`LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in images/posters/sample (no size specified)`

If I change the `sample` to `sample.jpg` all works, but I have a bunch of theses images for which I cannot change the suffix (another application depends on it).

Any advice?

Comment: If you cannot change the original name of the image you could use a link/alias/whatever this is called on your OS with the name `sample.jpg` that links to `sample`.

Comment: Sure, but the problem is I am including images from another system, and would prefer to avoid the overhead of copying / linking to images. Moreover, I have thousands of said images...

Comment: Generating the links can be automated ...

Comment: Call me lazy, but I would think there is a simple solution inside Latex

Comment: b.t.w, tried adding "\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,}% Note the trailing ',' which defines an empty extension", but still am getting an error

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: With `context` you could use something like  `\starttext

\externalfigure[test][method=png]

\stoptext` seems to work

Comment: Links may be just plain impossible - you could be working on a file system inside Dropbox.

Comment: Related: [Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72930/5764)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a simple solution, but here's a possible solution that adapts the internals command used by `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\jpg@Ginclude@graphics}[1]{%
  \begingroup
   \let\input@path\Ginput@path
   \filename@parse{#1}%
   \def\Gin@ext{.jpg}%
   \def\Gin@base{\filename@area\filename@base}%
   \Gread@jpg{\Gin@base}%
   \Gin@viewport@code\Gin@nat@height\Gin@ury bp%
   \advance\Gin@nat@height-\Gin@lly bp%
   \Gin@nat@width \Gin@urx bp%
   \advance\Gin@nat@width-\Gin@llx bp%
   \Gin@req@sizes
   \expandafter\ifx\csname Ginclude@jpg\endcsname\relax
     \Gin@drafttrue
     \expandafter\ifx\csname Gread@jpg\endcsname\relax
       \@latex@error {Can not include graphics of type: jpg}\@ehc
       \global\let\Gread@jpg\@empty
     \fi
   \fi
   \leavevmode
   \ifGin@draft
     \hb@xt@
     \Gin@req@width{\vrule \hss \vbox to \Gin@req@height{\hrule \@width
      \Gin@req@width \vss
      \edef\@tempa{\Gin@base}%
      \rlap{\ttfamily\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@tempa}%
       \vss\hrule}\hss\vrule
     }%
   \else
    \@addtofilelist{\Gin@base}%
    \ProvidesFile{\Gin@base}[Graphic file (type jpg)]%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{\Ginclude@jpg{\Gin@base}}%
    \dp\z@\z@\ht\z@\Gin@req@height\wd\z@\Gin@req@width\box\z@
   \fi
  \endgroup
}%

\newcommand{\includejpgnoext}[2][]{%
 \begingroup
  \let\Ginclude@graphics\jpg@Ginclude@graphics
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
 \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includejpgnoext{sample} % jpg image file called 'sample' with no extension   
\end{document}
```

It only works with PDFLaTeX.