# Image.png suddenly not found

Tags: errors

Latex compiled fine for me until a second ago, I don't know if I did something (I think not), but suddenly it threw me this error: no image ending in "png" loads. The folder with images is as usual, I think something was changed in the latex configuration that I don't understand how

In "message/log" it is written:

`I could not locate the file with any of these extensions: .eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps`

and

`! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in figures/decisiontree1.png`

I think I need to add "png". If so, how do I do it?

Attached photo where it does not compile any image

[image]

Comment: You should compile with pdflatex, not latex.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. How did you know I had that wrong?

Comment: It was a guess knowing that latex cannot process non-Postscript files.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comment.

Comment: I think @Werner|'s hint with non-Postscript files would be worth an answer, because I believe this is not common knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX with `dvips` can only includes a specific subset of images (see [Graphics file extensions and their order of inclusion when not specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72930/5764)). The most common include `.ps` and `.eps`. If you wish to include other formats (like `.png`, `.jpg`, ...) you'll have to use a different compile, like pdfLaTeX.

You `.log` shows

```
I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.eps,.ps,.eps.gz,.ps.gz,.eps.Z,.mps
```

which indicates the order in which the specific compilation driver searched for image extensions if it could find a corresponding image file. Switching to an appropriate compiler/driver for the image format (like pdfLaTeX in your case) or converting the image format before compilation will fix the issue.